# User's location not correct

Tags: java, android, android-location

I'm trying to get the user's current location for my weather application but i get the location of some "US" area. I've tried multiples tutorials but failed to get the correct current location.

It returns me:

latitude: 37.421998333333335

longitude: -122.08400000000002

The location is "Mountain View,CA,US"

The code I've used is below:

GpsTracker.java

```
public class GpsTracker implements LocationListener {

Context context;

public GpsTracker(Context c)
{
    context = c;
}

public Location getLocation()
{

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(isGpsEnabled)
    {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return l;
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

In my main class I'm getting the location like this:

```
public void getLocation()
{
gpsTracker = new GpsTracker(getApplicationContext());
Location l = gpsTracker.getLocation();
if(l != null)
{
    lat = l.getLatitude();
    lon = l.getLongitude();
}
    Log.d("User's location","Latitude"+lat);
    Log.d("User's location","Longitude"+lon);
}
```

Comment: use `FusedLocationProviderClient`

Comment: Can you provide some link or some code? I'm not familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

The Location that you need is returned in the method `onLocationChanged`.
So you could assign it to a variable and then return it:

```
private Location lastLocation;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;
}

public Location getLastLocation() {
    return lastLocation;
}
```

Call `requestLocationUpdates` in the `onCreate` of your activity and then call `getLastLocation` when you need to show it.

Or you can implement a callback to notify the activity when the location changes.

Comment: Can you provide me some more info on how can i get the latitude and longitude from the method "getLastLocation()"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the last known location and using that tool is probably handing back this address. Consider using a better tool or just FusedLocationProviderClient. However, I like SmartLocation library personally.

https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

It gives fallback providers in the event of one unavailable. There is a little learning curve to use the library, but once you implement it, it works nicely.